# Calculating Sharpe Ratio with semi-standard deviation

Tags: sharpe-ratio

Would it make sense to calculate the Sharpe Ratio with the semi-standard dev. So as to standardize/compare asset returns to their downside risk?

Comment: Something similar to this exists and is called the Sortino Ratio . You can find some discussion of it on this site, for ex. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/did-i-correctly-calculate-all-the-elements-of-the-sortino-ratio

Comment: To compare to only downside (negative) risk returns, use Sortino ratio.  The semi-standard deviation is the standard deviation of returns below the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside standard deviation there are many other risk measures as well. And of course Sharpe ratio can be generalized to use any risk measure:

$$ \text{Sharpe} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{\mu_R - \mu_F}{\text{Risk}_R} $$

where $\mu_R$ is portfolio return and $\mu_F$ is risk-free interest rate. And if you plot available portfolios on a 2D risk-return plane, Sharpe ratio of a given portfolio is just a slope of the line connecting risk-free asset with that portfolio, i.e. $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

For instance in R package *PerformanceAnalytics* there is a function which calculates Sharpe ratio taking as risk measure Value-at-Risk, Expected Shortfall etc.

So there is no obstacle to use downside risk in generalized Sharpe ratio formula. In fact, such ratio is sometimes called Sortino Ratio.